# Redirect after another redirect CakePHP3

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

After submitting a form, in a controller action, I need to open a pdf in a new tab and then redirect to another page. If I do this:

```
$this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $sale->id, '_ext' => 'pdf']);
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
```

I only get the pdf, but not redirects to "add" action.

How can I get the pdf, which is in URL .../view/saleid.pdf and then go to the add action?

**EDIT**

In add controller action

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add', $sale->id]);
```

Again in add controller action, at the top

```
public function add($saleId = null)
{
  if(isset($saleId))
    $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $saleId, '_ext' => 'pdf']);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're only getting to the PDF file because you're redirecting to it. After the redirection, execution is stopped, so the next redirection is not executed.

This, by browser limitation, can't be done: the app already sent the "download this" headers to the browser, so you can't redirect the user anywhere. What you can do is redirect to the end page first, and start the download from there.

Comment: It is a good idea to go to the second page first and then start the download, I try it and still get the same error. I get the pdf but I am not redirected.

Comment: How are you doing it? What happens if you remove the PDF download header, does it go to the page you want it to? Remember, you need to handle the download now in the resulting page's controller action.

Comment: I edited my question. If I remove the redirect to pdf download, I go to the page I want. So the problem is with the redirect.

Comment: You can’t redirect and open the pdf in a new tab. You need to make it so the browser downloads the file when it gets to the add action.

Comment: I think you're redirecting to a view that shows the PDF. You need to send the PDF to the browser, otherwise you're obviously going to be redirected to another view. Try this instead of redirecting to the PDF: `$this->response->file($sale->id, array('download'=> true, 'name'=> 'file name'));`

Comment: The problem is that the view action generates the pdf. I don't have the pdf in "add" action.

Comment: Then I'm afraid what you want to do is not possible (if I'm undestanding correctly). You can either have the PDF view send "download this" headers to the browser, or simply have a "Download here" link in your second page (I know, it's not a good option).